# Can't get entire png from PhantomJs render command

Tags: javascript, html, image, png, phantomjs

I am using **PhantomJS** for converting `html file into png`. Actually, my html file is bit lengthier in horizontal way.**PhantomJs** do not capture its image entire up to last horizontal scroll.I'm using render command for converting html into png.What exactly I am missing or is there any limitation phantomJS has ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer from `PhantomJs` Issue Blog https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12950

Answer (score 0):

Did you set an appropiate window size (viewport)? From this [example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/technews.js):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 320, height: 480 }; // <============
page.open('http://news.google.com/news/i/section?&topic=t', function (status) {
 ...
```

Comment: No..I am not setting any specific height and width..Setting height and width doesn't resolve problems.